# Display label (tableViewCell) outside from cell

Tags: ios, swift, function, label

Is it possible to display the **label** of the **tableViewCell** outside the cell? Ie, by default, the label appears in the function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell2

    cell2.currentPageNumber.text = "1/\(Images?.Photo.count ?? 0)"

return cell2
```

I want to display currentPageNumber.text in this function

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)

    currentPageNumber?.text = "\(String(Int(pageNumber) + 1))/\(Images?.Photo.count)"
}
```

And the **tableViewCell**:

```
class DetailTableViewCell2: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var currentPageNumber: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        currentPageNumber.layer.zPosition = 2
        currentPageNumber.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        currentPageNumber.clipsToBounds = true

    }

}
```

Is it possible to do? And if possible, how?

Comment: Why don' t you use value directly "1/\(Images?.Photo.count ?? 0)"

Comment: Can't use because **currentPageNumber** is inside in other class and i can use **currentPageNumber** only in function **cellForRowAt**, but me need use **currentPageNumber** outside from function **cellForRowAt**

Comment: When `func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` is called, you say you want to display `currentPageNumber.text`. But from which cell? The *Top* row? The *Bottom* row? The *middle* row? And --- Based on the code you've shown, `currentPageNumber.text` will have the exact same text in ***every*** row.

Comment: @DonMag i made little update in question about "will have the exact same text in every row.". About other. In **func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)** i want display **currentPageNumber.text** from **class tableViewCell**

Comment: This still doesn't seem to make sense... Suppose `Images?.Photo.count` is `8`... every row in your table will show "1/8"... then, the user scrolls and the scrolling stops --- `scrollView.contentOffset.x` will always be `0` (unless you mean `.y` and .`height`?)... even so, where do you want to put that string? Do you want to change the label ***inside*** one of the rows? If so, which row? Or do you have some other `currentPageNumber` label?

Comment: `scrollView.contentOffset.x will always be 0 (unless you mean .y and .height?)` no, if i make a `print("page number is \(pageNumber)/\(Images!.Photo.count)")`, i got pageNumber 1/10, 2/10, 3/10 and further or 3/10, 2/10, 1/10 when i scroll right if left. Just me need put it in **Label**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's helped me

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? DetailTableViewCell2 {

        let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)

        cell.currentPageNumber.text = "\(String(Int(pageNumber) + 1))/\(hallImages?.ImagesHalls.count ?? 0)"

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You got the visible cell IndexPath here

```
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

//replace your cell class and tableView Object
        for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
            let indexPath: IndexPath? = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
            print("\(indexPath)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Got an error - ambiguous reference to members "tableVIew"
if i understand you what **mainImageCollection** like a my **@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!**

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what means ** YourCollectionViewObject**? :((

Comment: **YourTableViewObject**